# Paypal Javascript Button data-notify-url Instant Payment Notification

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

Can we use `data-notify-url` attribute to received IPN?

```
script(src='paypal-button.min.js?merchant=username@email.com', data-button='buynow', data-name='My product', data-amount='1.00', data-env='sandbox', data-notify_url='http://example.com/ipn')
```

The payment was successful but it seems specified notify_url wasn't called.

I also used `Instant Payment Notification (IPN) simulator` and enter my `notify_url` but encountered the error below:

```
IPN Delivery Failed:503 Service Unavailable
```

But looking at the logs of my application, I can see the `notify_url` was called.

I used `web accept` as transaction type.

Answer (score 1):

This just looks like your Backend-Script (may it be PHP or anything else) is currently not available.
It can happen due to a server overload.

The 503 is a HTTP-ErrorCode so it has nothing to do with PayPal. PayPal tries to send the IPN to you and your web-server responds with a 503 error.